# Google maps getting overlay error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, layout, google-maps-api-3

I am working in google maps...

i did the bellow application and it was working fine then suddenly it stoped working and I trace it from the begining and I found that when I add

```
 mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
```

the application stops working...

I need a help please

```
public class MapGtugActivity extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener  {
MapView mapView ; 
MyLocationOverlay compass ; 
MapController controller ; 
Drawable drawable ; 
Drawable drawable2 ; 
List<Overlay> mapOverlays ; 
GeoPoint point1 ; 
GeoPoint point2 ; 
GeoPoint point3 ;
MapItemizedOverlay custom ; 
MapItemizedOverlay custom2 ; 
//List <GeoPoint> LGP ; 
 GeoPoint LGP[] = new GeoPoint[6] ; 
 Button AddLayers ; 

 int x , y ; 
 GeoPoint touchedpoint ;
 long start ; 
 long stop ;



   CharSequence[] items = {"Layer1", "Layer2"};
   boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length];



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview) ;
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true) ; 

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();




}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Application stops working does not make any sense here. Tell us what's happening. Show us your logcat

Comment: And I think u cannot call getOverLays in onCreate..After setContentView. You can only make calls to getOverlays after you have added overlays. I think its returning nullpointerException at that point. Because when getOverlays() is called there is no overlay defined on ur map..

Comment: it says the it is stooped it is not even force close... it is not working at all

Comment: I thought the same, please see the Editing that I did << as an answer to this question.. it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only make calls to getOverlays after you have added overlays. I think its returning nullpointerException at that point (because ur calling it in onCreate). Because when getOverlays() is called there is no overlay defined on ur map for it to get.